# Rails Debugging in a docker on a remote server from Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, debugging, rubymine

How can I connect the Rubymine IDE debugger with a remote running rails app running inside a container?

Comment: You can debug a Rails app using the remote Ruby SDK added via docker-compose (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#install_gems)